# How do I create a function_list<> class to a hold a vector of std::function<>s with the same template syntax?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, delegates, std-function

I wish to have a function_list<> template class that holds a vector of std::function<> values. A key point is that I want to declare my list with the same form I would declare a single std::function<>. e.g.

```
function_list<void()> functions; // list of std::functions that take and return void
```

Below is my attempt to implement this. I tried to follow the same syntax used by the std::function<> template in the *functional* header file of the standard library.

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<class _R, class... _Args>
class function_list<_R(_Args...)>
{
public:
  std::vector<std::function<_R(_Args...)>> functions;
  function_list& operator+=(std::function<_R(_Args...)> f) { functions.push_back(f); return *this; }
  void call_all(_Args... args) { for (auto& f : functions) { f(args...); } }
};

int main()
{
  function_list<void()> fl;
  fl += []() { std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl; };
  fl += []() { std::cout << "Goodbye, Cruel World!" << std::endl; };

  fl.call_all();

  return 0;
}
```

This doesn't compile and fails with the following errors (clang on OSX 10.14):

```
test.cpp:6:7: error: explicit specialization of non-template class 'function_list'
class function_list<_R(_Args...)>
      ^            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:9:28: error: function cannot return function type 'void ()'
        std::vector<std::function<_R(_Args...)>> functions;
                                  ^
test.cpp:14:24: note: in instantiation of template class 'function_list<void ()>' requested here
        function_list<void()> fl;
                              ^
2 errors generated.
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't understand what's wrong with using `std::vector<std::function<...>>` directly, but here's your answer:

```cpp
template<class _R, class... _Args> class function_list<_R(_Args...)>
```

This right there is a class template specialization.

But you need to declare a template first to be able to specialize it:

```cpp
template <class> class function_list;
```

---

But in fact you don't even need a specialzation. You can simply do:

```cpp
template <class T> class function_list
{
  public:
    std::vector<std::function<T>> functions;
};
```

---

Also note that names starting with `_` followed by an uppercase letter are reserved and must not be used. You should rename your template parameters. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply.

You are correct - once I created an empty class template first, followed by my class template specialization, my code then compiled properly.

I needed a specialization because I wanted to add another method which would call all functions in the list with the proper arguments. I omitted that for simplicity but I will add it in to the OP now.

Finally thanks for the tip about _[A-Z] names being reserved, I thought I was doing the right thing copying the standard library convention but obviously not.

Thanks again!

Comment: Oh, and std::vector<std::function<...>> was not sufficient because I was going to add an operator+=(std::function<..>) overload for delegate syntax.